# Insert records with databasequery (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

im trying to insert records with databasequery but when i submit the form i got this error and i don't know why

i tried this code in web.php:

web.php :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;



Route::post('/nav-store',function(Request $request){
    $data = array('nav-name   ' => $request['nav-name'],'nav-url' => $request['nav-url'],'nav-class' => $request['nav-class']);
    $query_insert= DB::table('nav')->insert($data);
});
```

here is the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nav-name ' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `nav` (`nav-name` , `nav-url`, `nav-class`) values (dsdd, sdsd, sdsd))

Comment: Remove spaces after nav-name... it should work...

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself time use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) then you can do this

```
$nav = new ModleName;
$nav->nav_name = $request->navName;
$nav->nav_url = $request->navUrl;
/// so on
$nav->save();
```

And that's it! very easy to look at and troubleshoot

Edit: as  lagbox pointed out the dashes are not good, Use _ for your DB.

Comment: sidenote: php will read those hyphens, `-`, as the subtraction operator so you can't use them that way